# How to properly setup Vuex store in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a problem in adding my store to the app component. It says, `this.$store is undefined`. Even though I followed the steps in the Vuex website and in some tutorials commonly found in the internet.

Here is my `store.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        titles: []
    },
    mutations :  {
        addTitles(title){
            titles.push(title)
        },
        removeTitle(title) {
            this.titles = this.titles.filter(data => data != title)
        },
        checkExist(title){
            if(this.titles.includes(title)){
                console.log("already existed")
                return;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

In my `App.vue` file:

```
  
</template>
<script>
import TodoForm from '../components/TodoForm';
import Card from '../components/Card'

export default {
  name: 'Main',
  components: {
    TodoForm,
    Card
  },
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'Roberts',
      titles: []
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.$store)
  },
}
</script>
<style></style>
```

And in the `main.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: tanga => tanga(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Here is my dependencies,

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0"
  },
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What versions of `vue` and `vuex` are you using (check your `package.json` dependencies)?

Comment: Something isn't quite adding up with your directory structure. How can `App.vue` which is apparently in the same folder as `main.js` and `store.js` import components from `../components`? Won't that put the `components` directory outside your project source folder?

Comment: I have updated the questions and added my dependencies in the project folder. @Phil

Comment: You cannot use Vuex v4 with Vue v2. See https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: the ```main.js``` is inside the folder, while the components folder was also inside the project source folder, the store.js file is really folder named ```store``` and an ```index.js``` inside it. I just have made a mistake in my question and it says ```store.js``` since not everyone can be clarified

Comment: Thanks @Phil, sorry for my english, maybe I need to downgrade by Vuex now....

Comment: Your English is fine, better than many native speakers 